# How can one avoid illegal characters when composing a URL?

Tags: base64

I'm writing a web application that *dynamically* creates URL's based off of some input, to be consumed by a client at another time. For discussion sake these URL's can contain certain characters, like a **forward slash (i.e. '/')**, which should not be interpreted as part of the actual URL, but just as an argument. For example:

```
http://mycompany.com/PartOfUrl1/PartOfUrl2/ArgumentTo/Url/GoesHere
```

As you can see, the **ArgumentTo/Url/GoesHere** does indeed have forward slashes but these should be *ignored or escaped*.

This may be a bad example but the question in hand is more general and applies to other *special characters*.

#### So, if there are pieces of a URL that are just *argument*s and should not be used to resolve the actual web request, what's a good way of handling this?

## Update:

Given some of the answers I realized that I failed to point out a few pieces that hopefully will help clarify.

I would like to keep this fairly language agnostic as it would be great if the client could just make a request. For example, if the client knew that it wanted to pass **ArgumentTo/Url/GoesHere**, it would be great if that could be *encoded* into a *unique* string in which the server could turn around and *decode* it to use.

Can we assume that similar functions like HttpUtility.HtmlEncode/HtmlDecode in the .NET Framework are available on other systems/platforms? The URL does not have to be *pretty* by any means so having *real words* in the path does not really matter.

#### Would something like a base64 encoding of the argument work?

It seems that base64 encoding/decoding is fairly readily available on any platform/language.

Answer (score 5):

You didn't say which language you're using, but PHP has the useful `urlencode` function and C# has `HttpUtility.URLEncode` and `Server.UrlEncode` which should encode parts of your URL nicely.

In case you need another way [this page](http://www.december.com/html/spec/esccodes.html) has a list of encoded values. E.g.: `/ == %2f`.

#### update

From what you've updated I'd say use Voyagerfan's idea of URLRewriting to make something like:

```
http://www.example.com/([A-Za-z0-9/]+) http://www.example.com/?page=$1
```

And then use the applications GET parser to filter it out.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [Apache rewrites](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html) to rewrite `http:// mycompany.com/PartOfUrl1/PartOfUrl2` to `http:// mycompany.com/path/to/program.php` and then pass in `ArgumentTo/Url/GoesHere` as a standard GET parameter. So what the server actually sends back is the response for `http:// mycompany.com/path/to/program.php?arg=ArgumentTo/Url/GoesHere`

Rewriting is a good way to guard against technology changes (so switching from PHP to ASP, for example, won't change your URLs) and provide friendly URLs to your users at the same time.

### Update

Using your example URLs and building on what I said before, I'd say to use this code in your httpd.conf or .htaccess:

`RewriteEngine On`

`RewriteRule http:// mycompany.com/PartOfUrl1/PartOfUrl2/([A-Za-z0-9]) http://mycompany.com/path/to/program.php?arg=$1`

(BTW, remove the space after the first `http://` in the `RewriteRule`, plus that line needs to contain *no* line breaks.)

Changing the paths, the filenames, name of the arg, etc. is fine; the critical parts here are the regex (`([A-Za-z0-9])`) and the `$1`.

Comment: Can anyone fix my post so it doesn't pull the Apache link through all the way to the middle of the update?

Comment: That was a bit random - I added spaces after the http:// parts but it really shouldn't have done that massive link. *slaps markdown*

Comment: The help page _does_ say SO hacked the parser a bit to support bare URLs and such... Might have something to do with it.

Comment: Anyway, thanks Ross. I added a note to let Scott know that the RewriteRule needs to have that extra space removed if he plans to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Base64 encoding your argument will work for you, however you'll need to make sure your entire URL is under the size limit of your target browser (2083 characters for IE 4 - 7, [according to this page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/208427)).

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking for, if using .net, is the HttpUtility.EncodeUrl() method, as it has many overrides. Look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlencode.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use the HtmlEncode and Decode methods on the server object.  I believe that will remove most characters that should not be and takes care of other things such as spaces, etc.

Here's the MSDN Article:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525347.aspx